# Como deshabilitar autocompletado de los input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Tengo el siguiente fragmento `html`:

```
<form id="formid" autocomplete="off">
<label class="control-label">Enter Code</label>
<input type="text" name="code" class="form-control" id="code" >
<br>
<label class="control-label">New Password</label>
<input type="password" name="npass" class="form-control" id="npass">
<br>
<label class="control-label">Confirm Password</label>
<input type="password" name="cpass" class="form-control" id="cpass" >
```

Pero cuando el usuario guarda credenciales de usuario y demás, estos campos me autocompletan. Quisiera que para este `form` no me autocompletara.

He probado poniéndole `autocomplete="off"` a los `input` también y nada. Incluso he usado el plugin `jquery.disableAutoFill.js` y aun sigue saliendo el autocompletado, alguna solución para esto?.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a darle al atributo un valor no válido

```
  autocomplete="nope"
```

Tomado de https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/desactivar_autocompletado_formulario

En algunos casos, el navegador continuará sugiriendo 
    valores de autocompletado incluso si el atributo 
    autocompletar está desactivado. Este comportamiento 
    inesperado puede resultar bastante confuso para los 
    desarrolladores. El truco para realmente no aplicar el 
    autocompletado es asignar un valor no válido al atributo

Comment: probe tambien esa solucion y aun sigue completando, incluso probe algunas variantes de otros desarrolladores de poner unos input antes ocultos y tampoco me funciono